# How to use flatten with SeqSelfAttention

Tags: keras, attention-mechanism

I want to use SeqSelfAttention , but in final layer the dimension need to be reduced. However, adding Flatten gives following error : `ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to Dense should be defined. Found None.`

Model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 200, 300)          5379900   
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_2 (Bidirection (None, 200, 40)           51360     
_________________________________________________________________
seq_self_attention_1 (SeqSel (None, None, 40)          2625      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, None, 40)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, None, 5)           205       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, None, 1)           6         
=================================================================
Total params: 5,434,096
Trainable params: 54,196
Non-trainable params: 5,379,900
______________________________________________________________
```

Need to add Flatten between dense_5 and dense_6 .

Comment: What is the shape you expect to obtain after the Flatten?

Comment: Expected ... (None, 5) .. This is a binary classifier and output should be 0 or 1. But output is coming as dimension of input vector - 300 .. Adding a Flatten layer solves the problem but error is coming due to SeqSelfAttention  layer